# What is the proper font for printing on thermal paper?

Tags: delphi, printing, fonts, report

I have a program that prints every client's order, like restaurants tickets, but I made it with times new roman. The result wasn't a quality print. I believe that the font is not the best for this tech and I have to convince my client the owner, cause he loves that font.

Would sans serif or similar be the better choice?

Also, is there a standard procedure for printing direct to those thermal printers and choose the internal fonts, whatever the manufacturer is?

I am using QuickReports to create the printing. The result is king of blur. I will put the pictures to compare as soon as I put my hands on a scanner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this; it's too localized (depends on your particular printer and other things specific to your needs), and is unlikely to be of use to future readers for that reason. I'd read your printer manual, do some experiments with different fonts, and show your client the different outputs to convince them to change. (And if they don't want to change after that, they *are* the client and are the ones paying you, but it's their app.) Good luck!

Comment: A thermal printer?  Good grief!   That's a hardware problem easily solved: Buy a good printer.

Comment: Since you have to change your program anyway, why not add some temporary test code that prints "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" in 20 different fonts?

Comment: Or leave that code in as a feature to let the user select a font. Then you're done in one step, and you won't have to convince your client.

Comment: This is not Too Localized because this applies to a whole class of printers, not just user's printers. It's also not off-topic because selecting a printer font is in part a technical decision, especially when dealing with special purpose printers.

Comment: I agree with @CosminPrund. I had questions closed because of that before. But that question had more than 300 views in a few hours because those kinds of questions are also very pertinent to many professionals and students because it's part of their work for life. Thank you all for your effort for making this community even greater, but sometimes you're just too hard. At least do not delete this and leave it for future reference. This way you don't have to re-delete when someone else came with a similar question.

Comment: I've checked the Benmatech 4200TH manual and it does not mention how to program directly to the printers output using their fonts. They don't even mention what fonts they have. I guess I will just have to use `lucida console`. Later I will pass the images of the prints for you.

Comment: I doesn't *list* the fonts, it lists `ESC` commands that you'll issue to get big fonts, small fonts, italics, etc. Look at the programmer manual, not the user manual: http://www.bematech.com/support/downloads/MA501.4421.00%20-%20Rev.1.4.pdf As for fonts, do a google search for bitmap fonts: you can install a font with your application, it doesn't need to already be installed.

Comment: I now see your edit. You should probably ask a separate question about sending "raw" data straight to the printer. But do a good search on SO first, I'm sure it's been asked before! Of course, you don't do that with Quick Reports. That's what I mean with "out of the comfort zone": no QuickReports, you send *raw* data to the printer. It's insanely fast too, once you figure it out.

Comment: Installing a font with your application is trivial - I've done it in a couple apps, embed the font file as a resource in your app, upon startup, check if that font is installed, if not, extract and install it. Easy enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Selecting the optimal print font is both subjective and technical. Not all fonts are suitable to small-dpi mediums; Some fonts use highly variable line width when painting the letters and that will "smudge" easily when used with smudge-prone mediums; I guess the thermal printer fits into both "small dpi" and "easily smudged" areas.

In my opinion the selected font should be, based on priority:

- The device fonts: don't print graphics to tiny printers, use the on-board fonts and learn the "escape" language. Results will be outstanding, and there's enough flexibility to also get beautiful results. The only time I had to deal with a thermal printer I used this method and the results really are *great*. The device allows font scaling, drawing lines, almost everything you'd need. But it is hard work and you'll be outside of the "comfort zone". The printer driver is not helping you at all and you end up writing device-specific routines.
- Next option would be BITMAP fonts. That is, don't use True Type Fonts. On today's computers bitmap fonts only serve one purpose: look good at small pixels count. That's perfect for a small-dpi printer.
- Invest millions in developing a special purpose font that's easy to read *on paper* and behaves good printed on whatever device. Or use the font others have spent millions in developing: open your favorite version of `Ms Word`, type a few words and see what font is used. Right now I get `Calibri`.
- Use a font that doesn't have fancy strokes that need many pixels to paint OR make smudges more obvious. Write something in `Times New Roman` in very large font. See the fancy lines, the narrow segments, the elegant design? That's not a good choice for a small-dpi, smudge-prone printer. Now do the same for Arial, Verdana, Tahoma.
- Let the user choose. This decision is only partly technical, there might be subjective reasons to use one thing or the other.

Comment: You can also get a list of the on-board printer fonts by looking at `TPrinter.Fonts` and removing the fonts that also exist in `TScreen.Fonts`.  Using those fonts in reports on the OP's thermal printer should improve print speed and quality dramatically without having to resort to raw, device specific output.  I've done exactly this with dot-matrix printers before.

Comment: I would move the last one about letting the user choose a bit higher up the list, since the user may already have hundreds of their own fonts which they wish to choose from. It's still a valuable point to default the fonts to a more generic selection though. I would personally try out Consolas.

Comment: @JerryDodge, if the user truly really has hundreds of fonts installed then it's not exactly an "average user", and given it's passion for fonts, that bullet will move all the way to position one, and if the printer can't cope with that then the user gets a new printer. More realistically the user only has windows-default fonts and doesn't really understand all the talk about small dpi. The developer should choose a default font that works well, only then allow the user to mess with the settings.

Comment: @CosminPrund That's exactly what I was trying to say, but in more brief words. "It's still a valuable point to default the fonts to a more generic selection though."